# How to change DataField of BoundField

Tags: asp.net

When using the `asp:boundfield`, can I call a C# function that return a string which corresponds to the column name instead of writing the column itself?

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes"/>
```

Instead of having `DataField="Notes"`, I want to have `DataField=FUNCTION_NAME`.

I tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
DataField=<% FUNCTION_NAME %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`DataField="<%=FUNCTION_NAME %>"` (extra equals)

What you had was simply an embedded code block which didn't have an output. However the = produces output to the page (similar to `response.write()`).

See the difference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28vs.80%29.aspx)